# Is it possible that the OS / some other app can cause my driver to hang for more than 1 second?

Tags: windows, drivers, operating-system

I have a driver that for one reason or an other it hanged for more than 1 second and crashed my app.

What possible causes do you know that can make a driver hang for more than one second inside an OS? Think here of special conditions, automatic updates, antivirus, etc.

My OS is Windows 2000.

Comment: How do you know it's a driver that's hanging?

Answer (score 1):

Almost anything, it could even be the driver itself.  Drivers are basically an low level application for communicating with something, they can have bugs, exploits and issues themselves just like any program.  I often find a lot of OS level issues stem from a bad driver.  There is one driver for HP management we have to downgrade to an older version because the one that came with the equipment causes a ton of errors and eventually triggers a random reboot.

Comment: Can it be that it's not the driver, but the OS who does something else and does not assigns enough priority to it?

Comment: I call a function from its API which returns a timeout error, signaling that it spends a lot of time extra on something which I can't actually inspect due to its closed source character.

Comment: Did you inspect the documentation on why it returned the timeout?  Given its actually telling you it would seem likely the driver was waiting on something else to occur.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "my driver" do you mean you wrote it? Then perhaps Coding Horror is a better place for this question.

Comment: It's a closed source driver which I access through its API. One of the functions in this API, which I call, returns a timeout error.